# How do you take the integral of $\int \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y(3-y)}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do you evaluate the following? $$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y(3-y)}$$

I have looked at the solution and I don't understand how they are taking the integral of this? They go from:

$$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y(3-y)}$$

to

$$\int \frac13 \left(\frac1y + \frac{1}{3-y}\right)\, \mathrm{d}y$$

and how they get to this second step confuses me. Where did they get this extra $\frac13$ from?

Comment: Are you sure thats the right equation? Do you mean $\int\frac{1}{y(3-y)}dy$

Comment: @John Yes that is what I meant. I'll fix that now. Sorry about that!

Comment: You might want to look up partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @ZainPatel Oh yes! I remember my teacher mentioning that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int\frac{1}{y(3-y)}dy$ can written into a more integrable form using partial fractions as given below:

$$\frac{1}{y(3-y)} = \frac{A}{y} + \frac{B}{3-y}$$

$$1 \equiv A(3-y) + By$$

$$A = B = \frac{1}{3}$$

$$\int\frac{1}{y(3-y)} \, \mathrm{d}y = \int\left(\frac{1}{3y} + \frac{1}{3(3-y)}\right)dy = \int \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{3-y}\right) \, \mathrm{d}y$$

You can then integrate the above wrt $y$

Comment: I fixed some typos (you had several $3$s instead of $y$s).

Comment: @Ian, Thanks, I was in the process of fixing them myself-cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Partial fraction decomposition gives:

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{y (3-y)} & = \dfrac{A}{y} + \dfrac{B}{3-y}\\
1&=A(3-y) + By
\end{align*}
Looking at the $y$ coefficients and the constant coefficients, we obtain the following two equations:
$$0 = A - B $$
$$1 = 3A$$

Which solve to give $A = B = \dfrac{1}{3}$.

Hence 
$$\dfrac{1}{y (3-y)} = \dfrac{1}{3y} + \dfrac{1}{3(3-y)}$$
or
$$\dfrac{1}{y (3-y)} = \dfrac{1}{3} \left(\dfrac{1}{y} + \dfrac{1}{3-y}\right)$$